# When introducing myself like 「＿＿です」, would it be better to say 私は at the beginning?

Tags: grammar

For example:
**「私はウィリアムです」** vs **「ウィリアムです」**

Comment: With "私は" it's more formal, without "私は" it's more casual.

Comment: I guess if you really care, you should use the family name (or the full name at least). Presence of 私は should be less important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need 私は regardless of the formality level. As long as everyone understands you're introducing yourself, adding 私は is simply redundant and unnecessary (although it's not harmful, either). Saying 私は won't make you sound polite or formal.

If you need to be very formal (e.g., in a job interview), consider using a humble verb like 申します:

> ウィリアムと申します【もうします】。

This sounds much politer than ウィリアムです or ウィリアムといいます.

Comment: I've seen videos (made by a Japanese) advising against the use of 私は here, claiming it to be less natural.